# What does the "48" mean in the code that converts uint to string in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I found this code when I searched for ways to convert uint value into string.
It's from OpenZeppelin: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/3dac7bbed7b4c0dbf504180c33e8ed8e350b93eb/contracts/utils/Strings.sol#L16-L36

```
function toString(uint256 value) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    // Inspired by OraclizeAPI's implementation - MIT licence
    // https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/b42146b063c7d6ee1358846c198246239e9360e8/oraclizeAPI_0.4.25.sol

    if (value == 0) {
        return "0";
    }
    uint256 temp = value;
    uint256 digits;
    while (temp != 0) {
        digits++;
        temp /= 10;
    }
    bytes memory buffer = new bytes(digits);
    while (value != 0) {
        digits -= 1;
        buffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)));
        value /= 10;
    }
    return string(buffer);
}
```

I can't understand what `bytes1(uint8(48 + uint256(value % 10)))` means, specifically what does the magic number `48` mean here. Appreciate it if someone can shed some light on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

48 is the [ascii value](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII-Table-wide.svg) for the character '0'.

The loop in question basically takes the value modulo 10 (that is, the least significant digit) and adds 48 to it, converting it to an ascii character. It then divides the number by 10 to do the same with the second least significant digit and so on.

As an example, if `value` is 437, the modulo leaves 7. That 7 is added to 48 to make 55 which is the ascii value for the character '7'. It then divides `value` by 10 to do the same with the number 43 to get the next character.

Comment: thanks a lot, Joachim, that makes sense now. should've thought of ASCII